# Script to display the time

Tags: javascript

I want to design the code in javascript which identify my local time.
And with respect to that display the time in country like USA, UK etc

Comment: Have a look at the Date object. Search for "date mdn" in any search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider using an API instead of writing it,
Here's a good one.
https://github.com/mde/timezone-js

Answer (score 0):

Create a Javascript Date object and use `toLocaleTimeString` 
[MDN Date reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)